# AngularJS Math issue

Tags: angularjs, math

I am trying to do some math with user inputs.

I have this basic objets to start with

```
$scope.shape = 
{id: 1, cx: 0, cy: 0, result: 0}
;
```

And the user can type the value of cx and cy into fields;

```
 <input ng-model="shape.cx" type="text" class="form-control" id="cx">
 <input ng-model="shape.cy" type="text" class="form-control" id="cy">
```

I want to multiply the 2 values cx and cy and show the result in another input.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="A" ng-model="shape.cx * shape.cy">
```

This is working, I can see the the result in the field but I get an error;

```
Error: [ngModel:nonassign]
```

I would also like to asign this result to `shape.result`.

How can I set the value of `shape.result` to be shape.cx*shape.cy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See here it could be done like this :**

**SCENARIO 1 : Result on Button Click : (Procedural Approach)**

```
<input ng-model="shape.cx" type="text" class="form-control" id="cx">
 <input ng-model="shape.cy" type="text" class="form-control" id="cy">
 <input type="button" class="form-control" ng-click="calculate()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="A" ng-model="shape.result">
 $scope.calculate = function(){
 $scope.shape.result = parseInt($scope.shape.cx) * parseInt($scope.shape.cy);
}
```

**SCENARIO 2 : As soon as Value Changes in text boxes : (Direct Approach)**

```
<input ng-model="shape.cx" type="text" class="form-control" id="cx">
 <input ng-model="shape.cy" type="text" class="form-control" id="cy">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="A" ng-model="parseInt(shape.cx) * parseInt(shape.cy)">
```

**SCENARIO 3 : Using $watch : (Procedural Approach)**

```
 <input ng-model="shape.cx" type="text" class="form-control" id="cx">
     <input ng-model="shape.cy" type="text" class="form-control" id="cy">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="A" ng-model="shape.result">

    $scope.$watch(function (){
        $scope.shape.result = parseInt($scope.shape.cx) * parseInt($scope.shape.cy);
    });
```

**Note** :

1. Scenario 3 is using $watch hence it should be not used untill and unless you're in real need of it.
2. Scenario 1 is best suited to you I think as it will make your concept.
3. Scenario 2 is a direct approach hence should be used after gaining some knowledge as well as experience(But it's short & best within 3 scenatios). It's a reference from @tapos answer

**Thanks & Cheers**

Comment: If I watch for result will it work as well since result is watching for something else?

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to watch for cy and cx changes and do the calculation when it change.

```
$scope.$watch('shape.cx', function() {
    $scope.shape.result = $scope.shape.cx * $scope.shape.cy;
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccmf07k2/

Answer (score 1):

Every language input field is string when a user enter any number in text box it is string

```
<input ng-model="shape.cx" type="text" class="form-control" id="cx">
 <input ng-model="shape.cy" type="text" class="form-control" id="cy">
```

so you need some work in your result box ix

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="A" ng-model="parseInt(shape.cx) * parseInt(shape.cy)">
```

then you get your appropriate result